# How To Run Web Browser in BackGround in Window Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone

I'm just create a project using web Browser. In this Browser, I open a music site and play the music in this site (mp3). what i want is the web Browser can run in background, that mean when i press start button i still running,i'm using window phone 8, what should i do? Any body help me!

Comment: No idea about WP8, but this sounds like a bad idea. Why not use the native music player functionality for this? Keeping a full-blown browser running just to play some music seems like a massive waste of resources.

Comment: I see if you open Internet Explorer and run a mp3 music online, when you go out and open another applicantion, it still running music, but why in web browser, it can't run? that's all my problem,

Comment: You can use BackgroundAudioPlayer for these things.What is need of using Web-Browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the **WMAppManifest** then click on **"View Code"**. It will look exactly like a XAML, Then scroll down to `<DefaultTask......./>` and add this attribute with this value `ActivationPolicy="Resume"`. Then the browser should run in the background whether you exit or launch some other app. If you have the browser set on the main XAML or whatever XAML you have on first start, it should work just fine!